# Question about Matsumura book Commutative Ring Theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I'm reading the book of Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory* and I can't understand 
a statement that he does, namely:

> If $A$ is ring, $M$ a finite $A$-module, $\mathfrak p\in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$, and $n$ is the dimension of $M\otimes\kappa(\mathfrak p)=M_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p M_{\mathfrak p}$ as a vector space over the field $A_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p A_{\mathfrak p}$, then $n$ is the cardinality of a minimal basis of the $A_{\mathfrak p}$-module $M_{\mathfrak p}$.

It is on page 35, is a little phrase but I'm having problems with it. My apologies for the notation, I'm using the notation of the book that is a little bit strange.

I think that it may be easy to see but in the moment it's difficult to me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he is referencing his own Theorem 2.3 on page 8, which states (among other things) that if $A$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ and $M$ is a finite $A$-module, then every minimal basis of $M$ has $\dim (M/\mathfrak mM)$ elements.

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact theorem that support the statement.  I did not remember it.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Nakayama's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma) and the precise statement appears on page 8 Theorem 2.3 of Matsumura. As Matsumura states on page 35, $M$ must be a finite $A$-module.

Comment: Nakayama's lemma is actually Theorem 2.2 on the same page, not Theorem 2.3 as your edit within the five minute window suggests.

Comment: Much like Zariski's Main Theorem, Nakayama's lemma has a tendency to manifest itself in various ways and they are usually (in my experience!) all referred to as Nakayama's lemma. However my first sentence is horribly worded and is now edited.

Comment: Thank you!, I think that Matsumura himself has the tendency to call to various corollaries of Nakayama simply as Nakayama's lemma.